# Conversion failed on value

Tags: sql-server

Who can help me on this?

```
select Battery_Volts
from ems
where Battery_Volts between 25 and 27
```

I am lost on this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '25.19' to data type int.

Comment: Can you please (a) format the code and the error, (b) improve the capitalization and punctuation,  and (c) paste the table definition (such as the `CREATE TABLE` statement, which will show the names & types of the table variables)?

Comment: The fact that you're getting this error suggest that the data type of `Battery_Volts` is `varchar`. Is this guess correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is correct, and you're using a `varchar` to store a numerical value, you could also try:

```
where Battery_Volts between 25.00 and 27.00
```

If you get a further conversion error, I imagine you have non numerical values in your data, which opens a further can of worms.

Comment: @JPPentz, consider changing the Battery_Volts column type to a decimal type to avoid the problem. It's best to store data using an appropriate type to ensure data integrity and facilitate ease of use. The query in you question would work with decimal since the integer literal will be implicitly converted to decimal due to SQL Server data type precedence rules.

Comment: I completely agree with @DanGuzman here. There is never a good excuse for choosing the wrong datatype.

Comment: I change to decimal(38,3) seems now fine, date still don,t want to change.

Comment: @JPPentz Date? What date?

Comment: Like 2018/06/06 that was imported the data type ts varchar(50) when i change it to datetime2(7) it gives me the error (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string)

Comment: Are all the dates in the format `yyyy/MM/dd`, and only represent a date? If so, try `CONVERT(date, REPLACE(YourVarcharDateColumn,'/',''))`.

Comment: Yes all is 2018-06-06 got to DATE but now i,m getting this error,Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: On this query, select battery_volts
from ems
where date between 2018-06-06 and 2018-06

Comment: Wait, you're storing dates as an `int`? Your data type choices are all over the place; and completely wrong. If you can, I suggest reimporting the database the correct types. Things seem to have gone really really wrong with your ETL.

Comment: Yes i delete the table change the date and import all, so the date is now date but when a do a look up it tells me the date is incompatible with int.

Comment: @JPPentz that's because it is. If you want to query a date, pass a deterministic date value (`yyyyMMdd`). For example `WHERE YourDateColumn  = '20180624'`.

Comment: MMM OOO dit not now, so how will i do n search between dates like this or not select Battery_Volts
from ems
where date between 20180627 and 20180627

Comment: Put single quotes (`'`) around your input value, like you would a `varchar`; as I have done in the above comment.